# PHP hide part of string

Tags: php, string, replace

I'm searching for the most elegant way in PHP to hide a string (for example an username).

For example, usernames should be shown as:

```
tim   will be shown as: t*m
```

So the username itself is not completely "cryptically", but no one can guess their login name or at least not for sure.

Comment: is this `j**n` would be valid for `john`? I mean, it's pretty simple to guess that  `j**n` is `john`, maybe, you should consider this kind of hiding `***n` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest and why would you say that `j**n` is `john` and not e.g. `jean`? Anyway, usernames are usually not so simple.

Comment: @dragoste, because, "John" is more popular name and has a much higher propability to match `j**n`

Comment: But usernames are unique. There will be only one `john` in the system. And also one `jean`. So it's already 50/50. Any other John or Jean will need to figure out some other username, so it doesn't matter how popular name it is.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$string = 'usernameTest';
echo preg_replace("/(?!^).(?!$)/", "*", $string); // u**********t
```

- (?!^) Checks if the character is not the first character in the string.
- . matches any character
- (?!$) Checks if the character is not the last character in the string.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was exactly the solution I was gonna suggest.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following `regex` along with [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function like as

```
(^.|.$)(*SKIP)(*F)|(.)
```

**Example**

```
$your_string = "Narendra";
echo preg_replace("/(^.|.$)(*SKIP)(*F)|(.)/","*",$your_string);
```

**Output :**

```
N******a
```

**Explanation of Regex:**

- `(^.|.$)` This'll capture the first and last alphabet of the word
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` This'll skip the above captured words
- `|(.)` Over here rest of the alphabets'll be captured and can be replaced further with your character i.e. `*` over here

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/bUIob)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function get_starred($str) {
    $len = strlen($str);
    return substr($str, 0, 1).str_repeat('*', $len - 2).substr($str, $len - 1, 1);
}


$myStr = 'YourName';
echo get_starred($myStr); //should show Y******e
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this for example:

```
<?php
function HideUN($username = "") {
    $replaced = "";

    # Count the characters in username and remove an extra asterik (*)
    # Substring, remove all characters and leave the first one and add the last one
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($username) -1; $i++) $replaced .= "*";

    return substr($username, 0, 1)."".$replaced."".substr($username, -1, 1);
}
# Call this function
$string = "John";
echo HideUN($string);
?>
```

The `substr()` removes all characters after the first one, then the `for()` loop, counts the characters from `$string` and then we gonna add the asterik (*) to an other variable called `$replaced`.

Then at the end we put them together in an echo. Output: `J***n`

Answer (score 0):

```
function Split_Hide_Name($name) {
$name = trim($name);
$split_name = explode(' ',$name);
foreach($split_name as $v) {
   $string []= strlen($v);
}
$number_of_letters_to_show = 3;
$first_name_length = $string[0];
$last_name_length = $string[count($string)-1];

$first_name1 = $split_name[0];
$last_name1 = $split_name[count($string)-1];

$fname_cover = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $first_name_length - $number_of_letters_to_show; $i++){
$fname_cover .="*";
}

$lname_cover = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $last_name_length - $number_of_letters_to_show; $i++){
$lname_cover .="*";
}

$first_name = substr_replace($first_name1,$fname_cover,$number_of_letters_to_show);
$last_name = substr_replace($last_name1,$lname_cover,$number_of_letters_to_show);

return $first_name.' '.$last_name;}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the substr_replace function

```
<?php echo substr_replace('tim','...',1,-1);?>
```

where 1 and -1 represent the number of characters that should be visible in both sides of the string